# Relationship between two objects with the same fractal dimension.

Tags: fractals, chaos-theory

I've been doing some research into fractal dimension (namely Minkwoski-Bouligand dimension) for my university dissertation and have found two seemingly unrelated objects that have the same Minkowski-Bouligand dimension. I have tried to draw parallels between these objects but I can't seem to draw a conclusion. I am aware that we see fractal dimension as a measure of 'roughness' and therefore these objects are equally as 'rough' but I don't really know what this shows. Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated here. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You *cannot* generally conclude, simply because two sets have the same fractal dimension, that they are concretely related in some other way. Consider the following set, for example:

[image]

This set consists of two copies of itself - both scaled by the factor $1/2$ and one rotated relative to the whole. If you know just a bit about similarity dimension, then you probably know that this means that the set has dimension
$$
\frac{\log(2)}{\log\left(\frac{1}{1/2}\right)} = 1.
$$
But the set certainly doesn't look anything like a line segment, which also has dimension 1. More concretely, this set is totally disconnected while a line segment is connected.

On the other hand, you can use fractal dimension to conclude that two sets are concretely dissimilar in some sense.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed and well explained reply. In regard to the last line, could you expand on this a little more please? Two of the objects I'm investigating are interstellar nebulae, formed by the same process however they have completely different Minkowski-Bouligand dimensions, namely 1.25 and 1.39 and I'd like to discuss this in my paper.

Comment: @M.Hatton Perhaps my response to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972676/comparing-fractals/) that asks about comparing fractals might help?